# Converting HTML/CSS templates into Wordpress templates: CSS image path changing

Tags: wordpress

I bought a template with the following structure:

```
css/..
img/..
js/..
*.html files
```

style.css is located in css/ folder.

In order to create a functional Wordpress theme, do I absolutely have to move style.css to the root folder and adjust all of the paths in style.css to match the new location of images? (cause they're not in ../img, but in img now).

Can't I just specify the style.css file path somewhere? Or does it have to be in root folder in order to be a valid template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you choose to include your CSS files (most likely in the head.php or the footer.php), you can call

```
<?php get_template_directory_uri();?>
```

You can move your CSS and IMG directories into your theme like this

```
wp-content/themes/your-theme/css/ and wp-content/themes/your-theme/img/
```

Then, when you want to include them in your theme you can do so like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo <?php get_template_directory_uri();?>/css/your-stylesheet.css"/> 

<img src="<?php get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/your-image.jpg"/>
```

In your stylesheet, just make sure your image calls are relative to the image directory and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to put style.css in the root folder. This is actually the minimum requirement of a valid WordPress theme.

However, the style.css in your theme folder only needs to contain information about your theme like this:

```
/*************************************************
Theme Name: YOUR THEME NAME HERE
Theme URI: http://yoururlhere.com/
Description: This theme was custom made
Author: Your Name Here
Author URI: http://yoururlhere.com
Version: 1.0
Tags: flexble-width

***************************************************/
```

As long as you have that, you can add as many other additional stylesheets in your CSS folder, and link to them in the theme header.

If you are looking to convert a basic HTML template into a WordPress theme, it's worth looking at [Theme Matcher](http://themematcher.com).

Answer (score 0):

also you can use your **custom static variables** for your theme.

put this line in your **functions.php** file.

```
define("ASSETS",get_bloginfo('template_url'));
```

This usage is better way i think, about sql queries.

**Usage ;**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo ASSETS; ?>/CSS/file.css"/>
```